# Is 'volatile' sufficient to prevent C++ compilers from optimizing out a silent write?

Tags: c++, volatile

I would like to write a function that triggers copy-on-write of a page, without having to modify any values in that page. A simple implementation:

```
void trigger_cow(char* addr){
    *addr = *addr;
}
```

doesn't work because GCC will optimize out the line. If I use volatile,

```
void trigger_cow(char* addr){
    volatile char* vaddr = (volatile char*) addr;
    *vaddr = *vaddr;
}
```

then this works under -O3.

Will this "hack" work under other compilers or optimization settings?

The description of volatile in most sites I've seen doesn't seem to describe what happens when you write to a volatile pointer, only what happens when you read from one. Thanks!

Comment: Why are you trying to force a copy on write early anyway? Unless you're trying to force the COW early to avoid paying the cost at some other time.

Comment: Could be a test or an experiment.

Comment: It's no _'hack'_, that's exactly the purpose of `volatile`.

Comment: Hi Jesus

The particular application is that we are working with a linux kernel module that gets invoked whenever a page in a certain region of memory gets copy-on-write'd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard (§1.9/8) requires that:

> The least requirements on a conforming implementation are:
>   — Access to volatile objects are evaluated strictly according to the rules of the abstract machine.

"Access" is defined as either reading or writing, so yes, your `*vaddr = *vaddr;` must read a value from `*vaddr`, and then write the same value back to `*vaddr`.

Answer (score 5):

That is exactly what `volatile` does... it forces reads and writes to happen exactly once each time a variable is accessed, and in the same order as the reads and writes appear in the program (they cannot be reordered).

Note that the *processor* can still reorder reads and writes<sup>*</sup>, so `volatile` is not particularly useful for multithreaded programming.

<sup>*</sup>Except on the Itanium ABI, but that's unique.

Comment: Just to clarify, `volatile` only forces reads and writes of that specific variable to *actually* read, and write, and in their specified order; however, all other surrounding, non-volatile variables can be reordered, or elided, by the optimizer.  Specifically, `volatile` does not cause a memory-barrier to occur.

Comment: No processor can move a write before a read, if that write has a data dependency on the read. Reality disapproves.

Answer (score 3):

Formally, any access to `volatile` variables constitutes *observable behavior* of the program. It cannot be optimized out and it cannot be reordered with regard to other elements of observable behavior.

Optimizations in C++ programs are carried out under that "as if" rule, which basically gives the compiler permission to do anything as long as it does not change the observable behavior of the program.